# Unable to create partition table/partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a strange situation at the moment and I am not sure if the issue lays on the side of the hardware.

I wanted to create a new partition table with Gparted as well as with cfdisk. Both applications confirmed that they created it. But afterwards the table is still not existent, not readable.

This is the error message which always occurs:
`Disk /dev/sde doesn't contain a valid partition table`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) Look at "dmesg" for answer. 
in shell,type this:

```
dmesg | more
```

Maybe you have adapters for CF, SD cards, etc. **without media inside.or broken** This shouldn't be a problem, until some file refer to disk by that name (for example in /etc/fstab, but there should be an UUIDs instead of /dev/sd?, by default).

Comment: dmesg does not want to talk to me regarding the issue with the partitioning, there is no information which could help resolving it. But it's not that important anymore because I used another device to reformat but I still had the same issue. So I tried to create the partition table again and now it also works on the computer again. Strange thing..

Comment: hmm, really strange.

Comment: Nevermind, I did not experience it another time until now.